# Regarding Tools installation via azure runbook on VM's

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

I am trying to install datadog agent via runbook on multiple Azure Virtual Machine (VM), I have uploaded binaries on Blob from where I can download on my local computer (for testing, it is working fine), but when I am trying to connect to Azure Vm via `$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $vm  -Credential $cred`, I am getting an error that Winrm server is having an issue. Even winrm is running fine on that server.

Just I wanted to know is there any other way to download binaries on a remote VM and install on it via Powershell or runbook. If there is an option, please suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your requirement can be accomplished using cmdlet [Invoke-AzVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-3.3.0) / [Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/invoke-azurermvmruncommand?view=azurermps-6.13.0) or [Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmcustomscriptextension?view=azps-3.3.0) / [Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmcustomscriptextension?view=azurermps-6.13.0).

Related scripts can be found [here](http://saemundsson.se/?p=726) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa98fbee-8c19-4885-a0ce-a93c92eeb559/change-pagefile?forum=azureautomation).

Just FYI, [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f86d31d6-ecb2-4aae-a615-fee08f53ccca/error-on-remoting-vms?forum=azureautomation) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9044cbf4-d0de-4853-88df-b4b94b8badd4/how-to-remote-a-vm-using-azure-runbooks?forum=azureautomation) are actual references for the above information.

Hope this update helps!